# Grep wilcard of unknown length In between pipes

Tags: grep

I'm trying to grep the following string:

Line must start with a 15 and the rest of the string can have any length of numbers between the pipes. There must be nothing in between the last 2 pipes.

```
"15|155702|0101|1||"
```

So far i have:

```
grep "^15|" $CONCAT_FILE_NAME >> "VAS-"$CONCAT_FILE_NAME
```

I'm having trouble specifying any length of numbers when using `[0-9]`

Comment: I forgot to add, the string is in the CONCAT_FILE_NAME file. The issue is with specifying any length of numbers in the grep.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `|`

```
grep -E '^15\|([[:digit:]]+\|)+\|$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the beginning must start with `15|` and there are a total of 5 pipes(|) and nothing between the last two pipes..  And any number of digits between the 2nd 3rd and 4th pipes.

```
grep "^15\|[0-9]*\|[0-9]*\|[0-9]*\|\|$" $CONCAT_FILE_NAME >> "VAS-"$CONCAT_FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
cat file
15|155702|0101|1||
15|155702|0101|1|test|
16|155702|0101|1||
```

```
awk -F\| '/^15/ && !$(NF-1)' file
15|155702|0101|1||
```

This prints a line only if it starts with `15` and the second last field, separated by `|` is blank

So this would be:

```
VAS-CONCAT_FILE_NAME=$(awk -F\| '/^15/ && !$(NF-1)' <<<"$CONCAT_FILE_NAME")
```

---

Another shorter regex that would work

```
awk '/^15.*\|\|$/' file
```

This search for all lines starting with `15` and ends with `||`

Comment: @1_CR Seems that person removed the -, so I removed comment. `grep` may be better in some and `awk` in some other :)